# Selenium how can I click each identical button in a list and submit a form

Tags: java, selenium, web-scraping

Url in question https://www.doctorxdentist.com/find-a-doctor

I wish to do the following steps

1. Filter list
   1.1) click area of medicine
   1.2) click dental
   1.3) click specialty
   1.4) click dentist
2. Click on the get quote button
3. Fill form
4. repeat but click on the next get quote button

This is my code so far. I was hoping the buttons are not unique in a way that I can use decrement for the xpath to get each get quote button but unfortunately their xpath is all the same.

P.S It seems that my initial clicking statements don't work as desired. If you can check them, that will be great

```
    package Script;

import java.util.List;
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;

import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import org.openqa.selenium.JavascriptExecutor;
import org.openqa.selenium.Keys;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebElement;
import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.interactions.Actions;
import org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.ExpectedConditions;
import org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.WebDriverWait;

public class DoctorXDentist {

    public static boolean isClickable(WebElement webe, WebDriver browser){
        try
        { 
        WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(browser, 5);
        wait.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(webe));
           return true;
         }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
        return false;
         }
    }


    
    public static void initiate() {
            System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "C:\\Users\\jinyi\\Downloads\\chromedriver_win32 (2)\\chromedriver.exe");
            /*
             * ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions();
             * options.setHeadless(true);
             */
            WebDriver browser = new ChromeDriver();
            browser.manage().window().maximize();
            browser.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(15, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
            browser.get("https://www.doctorxdentist.com/find-a-doctor");

            
            Actions action = new Actions(browser);
            // xpth -> go to clickable, copy xpath
            // Click Area of Medicine
            action.moveToElement(browser.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id=\"app\"]/div/div[1]/div/div[2]/div/form/div[4]/div/div[1]/div"))).sendKeys(Keys.RETURN);
            WebElement element = browser.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id=\\\"app\\\"]/div/div[1]/div/div[2]/div/form/div[4]/div/div[1]/div"));  
            isClickable(element, browser);
            // Click Dental
            action.moveToElement(browser.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id=\"select\"]/div/div[6]/label/span[2]"))).click();
            // Click specialty
            action.moveToElement(browser.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id=\"app\"]/div/div[1]/div/div[2]/div/form/div[3]/div/div[1]/div"))).click();
            // Click Dentist
            action.moveToElement(browser.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id=\"select\"]/div/div[3]/label/span[2]"))).click();
            List<WebElement> box = null; 
            for ( int i = 1; i < 200; i++) {
            box.add((WebElement) browser.findElements(By.xpath("//*[@class='box'][i]//*[@class='doctor']//button[text()='Get Quote']")));
            System.out.println(box);
            }
            // after get quote function completed
            
        // click on form
        //  action.moveToElement(browser.findElement(By.xpath("/html/body/div[5]/div[2]/div/section/div/div[2]/section/div[1]/div[1]/div/input"))).click();
    }
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        initiate();

    }

}
```

I'm getting the follow message as well, it doesn't say any error and I'm not sure what it means

```
    Driver info: org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver
Capabilities {acceptInsecureCerts: false, browserName: chrome, browserVersion: 83.0.4103.116, chrome: {chromedriverVersion: 83.0.4103.39 (ccbf011cb2d2b..., userDataDir: C:\Users\jinyi\AppData\Loca...}, goog:chromeOptions: {debuggerAddress: localhost:59331}, javascriptEnabled: true, networkConnectionEnabled: false, pageLoadStrategy: normal, platform: WINDOWS, platformName: WINDOWS, proxy: Proxy(), setWindowRect: true, strictFileInteractability: false, timeouts: {implicit: 0, pageLoad: 300000, script: 30000}, unhandledPromptBehavior: dismiss and notify, webauthn:virtualAuthenticators: true}
Session ID: 12f47c7e9735f47822adfbedf2dd3619
*** Element info: {Using=xpath, value=//*[@id=\"app\"]/div/div[1]/div/div[2]/div/form/div[4]/div/div[1]/div}
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstanceWithCaller(Constructor.java:500)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:481)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.codec.w3c.W3CHttpResponseCodec.createException(W3CHttpResponseCodec.java:196)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.codec.w3c.W3CHttpResponseCodec.decode(W3CHttpResponseCodec.java:129)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.codec.w3c.W3CHttpResponseCodec.decode(W3CHttpResponseCodec.java:53)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.HttpCommandExecutor.execute(HttpCommandExecutor.java:161)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.service.DriverCommandExecutor.execute(DriverCommandExecutor.java:83)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.execute(RemoteWebDriver.java:582)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.findElement(RemoteWebDriver.java:333)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.findElementByXPath(RemoteWebDriver.java:451)
    at org.openqa.selenium.By$ByXPath.findElement(By.java:394)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.findElement(RemoteWebDriver.java:325)
    at Script.DoctorXDentist.initiate(DoctorXDentist.java:49)
    at Script.DoctorXDentist.main(DoctorXDentist.java:68)
```

Comment: Hi, Can you please help me, here which button are you referring to- "unfortunately their xpath is all the same"

Comment: @DurgaPrasadBehera it's the Get Quote button

Comment: Give it a try with this -  //*[@class='doctor']//button[text()='Get Quote']

Comment: I can get the button but I need it to click the button below after submitting each form, also can you check if my previous clicking statements work? Thanks for your help!

Comment: This is giving unique data- //*[@class='box'][1]//*[@class='doctor']//button[text()='Get Quote']

Comment: Instead of "1", put it in a loop and remember that variable and hope it'll solve your problem.

Comment: Thanks! Do you think my previous click statement works?

Comment: Which button exactly are you trying to click? I have gone through the steps that you mentioned but its a bit not clear. :-)

Comment: Sorry let me update the code with details

Comment: @DurgaPrasadBehera updated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This code works fine for me. If this helps, please mark as answer.
Optimize the code.

```
WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 60);
JavascriptExecutor js = (JavascriptExecutor) driver;
        
    try {
         driver.get("https://www.doctorxdentist.com/find-a-doctor");
         driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
         driver.manage().window().maximize();
            
    // Click Area of Medicine
     wait.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[@class='collapse form-box']//b[text()='Area of Medicine']"))));
     driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[@class='collapse form-box']//b[text()='Area of Medicine']")).click();

    // Click Dental
     driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[@id='select']//span[contains(text(),' Dental ')]")).click();

    // Click Speciality
     driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[@class='collapse form-box']//b[text()='Speciality']")).click();

    // Click Dentist
     driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[@id='select']//span[contains(text(),'Dentist')]")).click();

    // Click on Submit
     driver.findElement(By.xpath("//button[@type='submit']")).click();
            
     wait.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@class='box'][1]//*[@class='doctor']//button[text()='Get Quote']"))));
            
     int size = driver.findElements(By.xpath("//*[@class='box']//*[@class='doctor']//button[text()='Get Quote']")).size();
            
     IntStream.range(1, size).forEach($ -> {
           js.executeScript("window.scrollTo(document.body.scrollHeight,0)");
           driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@class='box']["+$+"]//*[@class='doctor']//button[text()='Get Quote']")).click();
           driver.findElement(By.xpath("//button[text()='Cancel']")).click();
            });
            
        }catch(Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }finally {
            driver.quit();
        }
```

Comment: Can you advise how did you get your xpath? I do inspect element copy xpath and I'm always getting these/html/body/div[5]/div[2]/div/section/div/div[2]/section/div[1]/div[2]/div/input

Comment: These xpaths I have created, probably you can go through the tutorials or else you can check tools like ChroPath :)

Comment: You mean you manually wrote them? Thanks for introducing xpath, I'm using it now but I see different xpath from you

Comment: Yes, I wrote them manually. It depends on how you write, there are different functions and axes of XPath.

Comment: The speciality is a tricky one, the xpath from chrompath doesn't work